# отобрать столбцы из DataFrame не удовлетворяющие условию

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, index

Задача: из исходного DataFrame отобрать все столбцы, названия которых не содержатся в заданном списке имен.

Пример:

```
index a  b  x  d  y  f
1     0  1  0  1  0  1
```

**Надо отобрать все столбцы, кроме x,y.**

Ожидаемый результат:

```
index a  b  d  f
1     0  1  1  1
```

В документации нашел только как фильтровать с использованием тильды ([по булеву индексу](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing)), но синтаксиса для отбора колонок придумать не могу.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

воспользуйтесь [DataFrame.drop(columns=[...])](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html):

```
res = df.drop(columns=['x','y'])
```

или:

```
res = df.loc[:, df.columns.difference(['x','y'])]
```

результат:

```
In [26]: res
Out[26]:
       a  b  d  f
index
1      0  1  1  1
```

Comment: вариант с drop до обидного очевиден, в очередной раз спасибо! Вариант с loc на моем датасете чуть-чуть быстрее ( 70,9 ms против 72,2 на 30 кругах), но думаю, оба варианта условно одинаковы по быстродействию.